# Commutators of matrices and vector fields

Tags: lie-groups, vector-fields, linear-groups

The tangent space of $GL(n,\mathbb R)$ in the unit element is $Mat(n,\mathbb R)$ and its elements correspond to left-invariant vector fields on $GL(n,\mathbb R)$.

It is well-known that under this correspondence the commutator of matrices corresponds to the commutator of vector fields.

This can be shown by a direct computation which, though not difficult, is somewhat nasty because of the many indices you‘ve got to use.

My question: is there some conceptual argument explaining why commutators of matrices and vector fields are the same?

Comment: I'd say that you need to adjust what you consider to be " many indices"